# How to do a cascading decrement across multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have N columns: A, B, C, .. N each are decimal(8,2).
I want to write a stored procedure that takes a row id and a single decimal(8,2) X.

I want it to decrement A until A reaches zero OR until it has reduced it by X. If A reaches zero and X was greater that A then I want to decrement B by X - A's original value and so on.

example:

```
select * from foo_table where id = 0;

| id| A | B | C |..
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 5 | 3 | 2 |

call my_stored_proc(0,9);
select * from foo_table where id = 0;

| id| A | B | C |..
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

What would be the recommended and performant way of doing this?

Comment: How many columns do you have? It should be fixed number

Comment: Can you show us the progression of numbers from each step arriving at `0, 0, 1` ?  There may be an easier solution than what you are imagining.

Comment: Whatever the problem, the recommended and performant solution if using an RDBMS would be normalisation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample data this query does the job:

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (

    SELECT
    t.id,
    GREATEST(A - @a, 0) A,
    @a := GREATEST(@a - A, 0),
    GREATEST(B - @a, 0) B,
    @a := GREATEST(@a - B, 0),
    GREATEST(C - @a, 0) C,
    @a := GREATEST(@a - C, 0)
    FROM
    t
    , (SELECT @a := 9) var_init_subquery
    WHERE id = 0
    ORDER BY id

) sq ON t.id = sq.id
SET t.A = sq.A
, t.B = sq.B
, t.C = sq.C;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8dfc/1/0)
- [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) you can read more about variables in queries